# Is there position statement on academic research workplace

Tags: workplace, community

I wonder if there is any professional research organization (like [Society for Neuroscience](https://www.sfn.org/) or [National Academy of Science](http://www.nasonline.org/)) that released an independent [position statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_paper) or an [opinion piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_piece) published in reputable journal that addresses best practices for research workplace.

I am looking for a written document that answers the question:

> In what conditions academic researchers want to work?

Conditions include paid family leave, building quality, office space, infrastructure, budgeting standards, how students are treated, benefits *etc*.

For this question by "academic researchers" I mean tenured and research professors, maybe postdocs at [R1 universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_I_university). But other similar answers are encouraged.

Here are examples of existing statements, but they don't address institutional policies or workplace enough:

- [Building a Culture of Research: Recommended Practices](https://www.hanoverresearch.com/media/Building-a-Culture-of-Research-Recommended-Practices.pdf)
- [How to build a better PhD](https://www.nature.com/news/how-to-build-a-better-phd-1.18905)
- [Key Strategies for Building Research Capacity of University Faculty Members](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10755-017-9394-y)

Comment: This, from a UK academic union, is definitely not "independent", but might address some of what you're after? https://www.ucu.org.uk/media/2748/Hot-desking-open-plan-offices-and-space-utilisation---UCU-factsheet/doc/hsbrief_hotdesk.doc

Comment: @Flyto Yes, that is somewhat looking like what i wanna see.